# Is there any Project Management FLOSS that has Resource leveling?

Tags: software-rec, opensource-projects

[An explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_leveling) of what Resource leveling is.

Comment: I think the answer is "no", sorry. The closest thing is "planner", but not [there yet](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132917). However, the new trend is web apps, such as [manymoon](https://www.manymoon.com/auth/login) that work great in Chromium on Linux.

Comment: @keith You sure that Planner is that advanced? I thought openproj had more features.

Comment: No, I don't think it is advanced. It's pretty basic. I didn't know about openproj, but now I see it looks pretty good. Except that it's written in Java.... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[TaskJuggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/) is a FLOSS (GPLv2) project management software with resource leveling.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [openproj](http://openproj.org/openproj)? I have never used it myself, but that's the closest that I know of.

Comment: Last updated in 2008?